# Why does the ASP.NET error page return 404 as soon as the aspxerrorpath querystring is present?

Tags: asp.net

I have configured an ASP.NET application as follows:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx"/>
```

When I browse to the ~/Error.aspx file the server returns 200 and the page is rendered. But if the user is redirected to the error page a querystring is appended to the path:

/Error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/Test.aspx

But whenever this querystring is used the server doesn't render the error page, instead it returns a 404 using the server's custom error page, not Error.aspx

Why doesn't the web.config setting result in ~/Error.aspx being rendered?

Comment: What exactly gets appended? What is the resulting URL?

Comment: @Oded I edited the question with the resulting URL including the querystring that's added by ASP.NET when redirecting the user in case of an error. In this example, Test.aspx would be a page that causes an exception, like a DivideByZeroException for example.

Comment: I have the same problem. It does not occur on IIS 5.1 on my local machine, but does on my hosting server. Other querystrings do not cause the problem, and it doeos not matter what comes after the = sign (can be completely blank). In fact, you can even type aspxerrorpath without the equals and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've tracked down the problem. Due to a recent ASP.NET security vulnerability ([see Scott Guthrie's post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/24/update-on-asp-net-vulnerability.aspx)), one of the recommended actions was to put in a URLScan rule that prohibits any urls with a querystring with "aspxerrorpath=" in it. So your url is cut off before it even gets to ASP.NET and a default 404 is returned.

To check if this is your problem, you can "aspxerrorpath=xx" to ANY page url on your site, and it should return a 404 error.

Now that a patch has been released to fix this vulnerability in asp.net, you should be able to get rid of that rule and then your error page redirects should work again.

Comment: `http://server/app/thisistest.aspx?aspxerrorpath=` still causes the error. The error is captured in Application_Error, but not properly handled == not redirected to site from custom errors (in web.config). This applies for ASP.NET 4.0