# aspxerrorpath=/ in url causes custom error page to not work

Tags: asp.net, custom-error-pages

I'm trying to get a site pci compliant.

If you visit (dummy ip):
    http:someipaddress/ZNYTMHXO.ashx

Then the user correctly sees the html from the page I have stated in my web config:

However if you use the same url but with ?aspxerrorpath=/ in the query string:
    http:someipaddress/ZNYTMHXO.ashx?aspxerrorpath=/

Then the page displays a Server Error in '/' Application. runtime error.

This is failing the pci scan.

Why is this variable causing an issue?

Sorry I should state that ZNYTMHXO.ashx does not exist. 404 redirect works when asperrorpath is not in the querystring.

-----UPDATE-----
Just to help, this is the html of the page that shows, very limited.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Runtime Error</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
            <br><br>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There should be additional information with the `Server Error in '/' Application` message -- perhaps `Description` and / or `Compiler Error Message` or `Source Error`?

Comment: Just added the html to the above...

Comment: The key to understanding the error page output is in the `Description`.  It says "An exception occurred while processing your request. **Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception.** The request has been terminated."  This is the not-so-fun scenario that occurs when your error handling incurs an error itself while it is processing another  error.  Check my posted answer though -- I think that is where you will find what you need to correct to pass your PCI compliance test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following blog post from ScottGuthrie http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/24/update-on-asp-net-vulnerability.aspx should be helpful.

He describes how to use the IIS Url Scan module to:

> disallows URLs that have an “aspxerrorpath=” querystring attribute
>   from making their way to ASP.NET applications, and will instead cause
>   the web-server to return an HTTP error.  Adding this rule prevents
>   attackers from distinguishing between the different types of errors
>   occurring on a server – which helps block attacks using this
>   vulnerability.

He was writing about a vulnerability that was reported to be patched.  However some are reporting this is still problematic as late as .Net 4.0 (mentioned here: [Why does the ASP.NET error page return 404 as soon as the aspxerrorpath querystring is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097184/why-does-the-asp-net-error-page-return-404-as-soon-as-the-aspxerrorpath-querystr))

Your PCI scan is likely trying to exploit this same vulnerability.  Eliminate the vulnerability and you should pass.

Hope that helps.