# aspxerrorpath=\errorpage.aspx query string appending to url

Tags: asp.net

i have defined custom error in **web.config** file.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorPage.aspx"/>     
</customErrors>
```

whenever it redirecting to Error page aspxerrorpath query string is appending, i'm getting

> Server Error in '/' Application Runtime Error

instead of Error page.

can anyone please provide me suggestion, how to avoid Querystring getting appending?

Comment: url looks like this  " http://abc12344/ErrorPage.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/ErrorPage.aspx"

Comment: possible duplicate of [aspxerrorpath=/ in url causes custom error page to not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959432/aspxerrorpath-in-url-causes-custom-error-page-to-not-work)